# How to disable iPhone Safari to launch the Maps application

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, maps

When you tap on a written address in Safari on iPhone, the Maps application is launched automatically. The address is **not** a link, just `<p>Mainstreet 1, Town</p>`

How can I disable this?

Comment: Why do you want to, it just the phone detecting an address making it more easy for the user to locate it.

Comment: Because on specific overview pages we don't want to launch the Maps app and keep the user within the website.

Answer (score 0):

just use atomic web browser and set the option to identify browser as IE9 for example.

ah sorry reread the question...